# Comparar caracteres en python independiente del color

Tags: python, comparaciones, color, text

Estoy intentando comparar caracteres en python, el problema es que estos tienen colores, ya sea haciendo uso de

`'\033[94m' + 'texto a color'+'\033[0m' #color de texto azul`

o usando colorama

`Fore.RED + 'texto a color'`

Si intento comparar, por ejemplo

```
texto1 = Fore.RED + 'some red text'
Style.RESET_ALL
texto2 = 'some red text'
print(texto1.__eq__(texto2))
```

Me sale que es falso ya sea con _*eq_* o con ==, tengo entendido que esto es porque concatena la cadena con otros caracteres haciendo así que obviamente no sean iguales
Mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de hacer que sea verdadero independientemente del color?

Gracias!

Comment: Y por que quieres comparar texto con colores diferentes? Que tal si primero comparas los textos y luego, cuando los tienes que mostrar en consola, les das el color?

Comment: Estoy comparando si el texto se encuentra dentro de una lista pero antes la lista ya tenía color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es crear una subclase de string que incluya el atributo color usando la clase `UserString` del módulo `collections`

En nuestra subclase manejaremos un atributo llamado `color`, que usaremos dentro del método `__str__()`, para proporcionar una versión del texto con color.

El manejo del color es simple: es una cadena arbitraria que se antepone al texto cuando se invoca `__str__()`. En este ejemplo usaremos secuencias de escape convencionales.

```
class ColorString(UserString):
    def __init__(self, texto, color):
        super().__init__(texto)
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.color}{super().__str__()}"
```

Con esto conservamos todos los métodos de `str`, lo que operan  sobre el texto, no sobre el color. Para el resto del código, nuestra clase `ColorString` funciona igual que un string básico.

#### Demo

```
from collections import UserString

class ColorString(UserString):
    def __init__(self, texto, color):
        super().__init__(texto)
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.color}{super().__str__()}"

mensaje1 = ColorString("hola", '\033[94m')
mensaje2 = ColorString("hola", '\033[31m')
print(mensaje1, mensaje2)

# Volver texto por default a blanco
print(ColorString("", "\033[0m"))

if mensaje1 == mensaje2:
    print("Textos son iguales")
else:
    print("Textos son distintos.")
```

produce:

[image: Texto con colores]